# What are the implications of "awaiting" for a synchronous function/method

Tags: node.js, typescript

Let's say I have the following TypeScript implementation:

```js
interface SomeInterface {
  bar(): Promise<string> | string
}

class SynchronousImplementation implements SomeInterface {
  bar(): string {
    return 'Hello Sync!'
  }
}

class AsynchronousImplementation implements SomeInterface {
  bar(): Promise<string> {
    return Promise.resolve('Hello Async!')
  }
}

class ConcreteClass {
  constructor(
    private readonly implementation: SomeInterface
  ) {}

  foo() {
    return this.implementation.bar()
  }
}

(async () => {
  const asynchronousImplementationInstance = new AsynchronousImplementation()
  const synchronousImplementationInstance = new SynchronousImplementation()
  const someConcreteClassInstance = new ConcreteClass(asynchronousImplementationInstance)
  const anotherConcreteClassInstance = new ConcreteClass(synchronousImplementationInstance)

  const someResult = await someConcreteClassInstance.foo()
  const anotherResult = await anotherConcreteClassInstance.foo()
})()
```

Is there any undesired implicit consequences of "awaiting" for a function that in practice is synchronous, such as `await anotherConcreteClassInstance.foo()`, in terms of performance, memory usage, event loop or anything related to runtime?

Comment: If you await a non-promise it just resolves immediately to the value, so `await foo` is just `Promise.resolve(foo).then(...)`.

Comment: Well, considering that, will the task be queued on the event loop, potentially resulting in a more memory expensive runtime (and also in a potentially slower execution)? Case yes, this is what I would like to get more detailed information about.

Comment: Why would queuing a task be memory expensive? If it was, then the potentially *hundreds* of tasks that are queued over the course of a few seconds would surely be crashing browsers all the time.

Comment: I haven't said "expensive" loosely. I said "more expensive" in comparison to how expensive it would be in case the queuing was avoided somehow. I am neither saying it would crash, it very much depends on the complexity of the process you are running and what are your infrastructure limitations. The question is regards the underlaid impact of such language level approach, not if this is correct/valid/possible code.